# How to Connect to an API in Your React Native With Expo?

Tags: api, react-native, laravel-5, localhost

**Api**

Api is made by laravel in my local environment.

ApiController

```php
public function test(Request $request)
{
    $test = Test::all();
    return response()->json($test, 200);
}
```

When I get http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/test, it works.

---

**React Native With Expo**

When I did `expo start`, this project has started on http://localhost:19002/

App.js

```js
componentDidMount() {
  axios
    .get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/test')
      .then((response) => {
        console.log(response);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
      });
}
```

I got an error:(

```
Network Error
- node_modules/axios/lib/core/createError.js:15:17 in createError
- node_modules/axios/lib/adapters/xhr.js:80:22 in handleError
- node_modules/event-target-shim/dist/event-target-shim.js:818:20 in EventTarget.prototype.dispatchEvent
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Network/XMLHttpRequest.js:575:10 in setReadyState
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Network/XMLHttpRequest.js:389:6 in __didCompleteResponse
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/vendor/emitter/EventEmitter.js:189:10 in emit
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/BatchedBridge/MessageQueue.js:425:19 in __callFunction
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/BatchedBridge/MessageQueue.js:112:6 in __guard$argument_0
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/BatchedBridge/MessageQueue.js:373:10 in __guard
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/BatchedBridge/MessageQueue.js:111:4 in callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue
* [native code]:null in callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue
```

I check this project on Expo Client App on iPhone.

I would appreciate it if you could give me any advice:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Expo doc say:

> By default, iOS will block any request that's not encrypted using SSL.
> If you need to fetch from a cleartext URL (one that begins with http)
> you will first need to add an App Transport Security exception. If you
> know ahead of time what domains you will need access to, it is more
> secure to add exceptions only for those domains; if the domains are
> not known until runtime you can disable ATS completely. Note however
> that from January 2017, Apple's App Store review will require
> reasonable justification for disabling ATS. See Apple's documentation
> for more information.

https://docs.expo.io/versions/v37.0.0/react-native/network/#using-fetch

Comment: Thank you. I'm going to use https request instead of fetching localhost.